# C++ - Simulation too slow using TCP/IP

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, optimization, tcp

I have two simulations running in two computers which generates data.
To connect these two simulations, I have a block running (IPTunnel) which transmits the data from one simulation to the other (on the other computer) to keep it running.
The problem is the optimization of the TCP connection.

The two simulations on one computers take about 3 minutes but when it's on 2 computers, take about 1 hour.

What can I do to improve the speed of the TCP connection?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code to send the data:

```
void IPTunnel::ipTunnelSendInt(int space) {
    int data = space;
    char* tosend = (char*)& data;
    int remaining = sizeof(data);
    int result = 0;
    int sent = 0;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        result = send(clientSocket, tosend + sent, remaining, 0);
        if (result > 0) {
            remaining -= result;
            sent += remaining;
        }
        else if (result < 0) {
            //printf("ERROR sending int!\n");
            // probably a good idea to close socket
            break;
        }
    }
}

int IPTunnel::ipTunnelRecvInt() {
    int value = 0;
    char* recv_buffer = (char*)& value;
    int remaining = sizeof(int);
    int received = 0;
    int result = 0;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        result = recv(clientSocket, recv_buffer + received, remaining, 0);
        if (result > 0) {
            remaining -= result;
            received += result;
        }
        else if (result == 0) {
            printf("Remote side closed his end of the connection\n");
            // probably a good idea to close socket
            break;
        }
        else if (result < 0) {
            //printf("ERROR receiving int!\n");
            // probably a good idea to close socket
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}

(....)

case signal_value_type::t_message:
        for (int k = 0; k < process; k++) {
            t_message message;
            inputSignals[0]->bufferGet(&message);

            t_message_type valueMType = MessageProcessors::getMessageType(message);
            t_message_data_length valueMDataLength = MessageProcessors::getMessageDataLength(message);

            ipTunnelPut(valueMType);
            ipTunnelSendInt(valueMDataLength);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Point of sending msg length

            string data = message.messageData;

            ipTunnelSendInt((int)data.size());
            int numberOfMessages = (int)ceil(data.size() / 511.0);
            string tmpMsg;
            int msgSent = 0;
            int msgToSend = (int)min(data.size(), 511);

            for (int it = 0; it < numberOfMessages; ++it) {
                char msg[512];


                tmpMsg.assign(data.begin() + msgSent, data.begin() + msgSent + msgToSend);
                msgSent = msgSent + msgToSend;
                msgToSend = (int)min(data.size() - msgSent, 511);
                //acrescentar if se o size for maior que msg
//              if (valueMDataLength > 512)
//                  printf("TAMANHO É MAIOR QUE 512");
                strncpy_s(msg, tmpMsg.c_str(), sizeof(msg));

                //                  msg[sizeof(msg) - 1] = 0;

                int strSz = (int)strlen(msg);


                char* tosend = (char*)& msg;
                int remaining = strSz;
                int result = 0;
                int sent = 0;
                while (remaining > 0) {
                    result = send(clientSocket, tosend + sent, remaining, 0);
                    if (result > 0) {
                        remaining -= result;
                        sent += remaining;
                    }
                    else if (result < 0) {
                        printf("ERROR!\n");
                        // probably a good idea to close socket
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
```

This is the general code of the block:

```
#include "../include/ip_tunnel_ms_windows_20180815.h" 
#include "../include/message_processor_common_20190410.h"


SOCKET clientSocket;
int n = 0;
void IPTunnel::initialize(void)
{

    if (inputSignals.empty()) {
        printf("server%d\n", n++);
        if (!server()) {
            printf("Error opening server\n");
            ::exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("client%d\n", n++);
        if (!client()) {
            printf("Error opening client\n");
            ::exit(1);
        }
    }
}


bool IPTunnel::runBlock(void)
{
    .....
    (transmit data)
    .....
    return true;
}

void IPTunnel::terminate(void) {
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

bool IPTunnel::server() {
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = ntohs(tcpPort);
    //inet_pton(AF_INET, (PCSTR)remoteMachineIpAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr.s_addr); // hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ipAddressServer.c_str());
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    if (::bind(listening, (sockaddr*)& hint, sizeof(hint)) < 0) {
        printf("\n ERROR on binding");
        return false;
    }

    if (listen(listening, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
        printf("\n ERROR on binding");
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)& client, &clientSize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)& client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }
    return true;
}

bool IPTunnel::client() {

    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return false;
    }

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(tcpPort);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, remoteMachineIpAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    int connResult = -2;
    while (connResult != 0 || numberOfTrials == 0) {
        connResult = connect(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)& hint, sizeof(hint));
        if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            cerr << "Waiting " << timeIntervalSeconds << " seconds." << endl;
        }

        Sleep(timeIntervalSeconds * 1000);
        ;
        if (--numberOfTrials == 0) {
            cerr << "Reached maximum number of attempts." << endl;
            ::exit(1);
        }
    }
    cout << "Connected!\n";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can improve the speed of TCP by using UDP instead.

Comment: instead of trying to optimize the tcp connection you should modify your simulation to require as little data transfer as possible. io is slow and io over the network is super slow, there is not much you can do about that

Comment: What can I do to improve the speed of the TCP connection? Use a shorter cable! :P

Comment: "The two simulations on one computers take about 3 minutes but when it's on 2 computers, take about 1 hour." - Have you considered just running it on one computer then? The overhead of running it on two seems excessive.

Comment: But the intention of this block it to transmit data so the simulations can run on separate computer.. So I really need to use it like this. Isn't there any way programatically to improve speed?

Comment: @nada If you need guaranteed delivery and deterministic ordering of messages etc etc. Then building that on top of UDP very easily results in reimplementing TCP.

Comment: @JesperJuhl exactly, and actually a colleague tried with UDP and the difference isn't significant (still slow)...

Comment: It looks like you send individual `int`s. You could try pre-building a buffer with everything you'd like to send and then send it with one `send` call. That should minimize the IP overhead at least.

Comment: The shown code appears to send data in small 4 or 8 byte chunks. This is going to be horribly inefficient. You need to optimize the shown code so that it sends and receives data in much larger chunks.

Comment: Also make sure that you are testing a optimized (aka release) build of your software, and not a unoptimized debug build. The C++ compilers optimizer can often do impressive things to speed stuff up (although it probably can't do much about inefficient network communication - but still).

Comment: And using TCP_NODELAY, does it affect in any way?

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY`, if enabled, will cause the TCP layer to send out a TCP packet as soon as possible rather than waiting up to 200mS to see if your application will call `send()` again in the very near future.  If you're going to call `send()` with only 4-8 bytes of data at a time, then enabling `TCP_NODELAY` will make things very inefficient since TCP will be sending out lots of very tiny packets.  So don't enable `TCP_NODELAY` unless/until you've first modified your code to collect a reasonably large amount of data (e.g. 100+ bytes) to pass to `send()` on each call.